# Required em select não funciona se mudar a ordem

Tags: html, html5

Se o option vazio estiver em outro lugar que não seja a primeira posição, ele não valida. pq isso ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            <select  required >
    
                <option value="0,00">0,00</option>
                <option selected=""> Selecione </option>
                <option value="+0,25">+0,25</option>
                <option value="+0,50">+0,50</option>
                <option value="+0,75">+0,75</option>
                <option value="+1,00">+1,00</option>
            </select>


            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Pq o required só valida a valor vazio se ele for o primeiro option?]

Comment: Mas isso aqui está errado... no seu código final está dessa forma? `<option selected="">`

Comment: @hugocsl eu acho que entendi, ele que que a opção 2 seja o "selecione" por isso o `selected`, porem se realmente ele for a segunda opção, ele não valida,

Comment: o selected ou selected="" o resultado é o mesmo.
O que não entendo é pq a ordem do 'selecione' afeta a validação, só valida se ele tiver na primeira, não sei o pq disso

Answer (score 0):

O atributo selected em um [option](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/option) de um [select](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Html/Elements/select) funciona de forma que seja a opção padrão, que já seja selecionada. 
Já o value é o conteúdo que é enviado. Logo se você quer que seja enviado a palavra 'Selecione' e independente do lugar que você coloque o selected ele irá funcionar.
Veja um exemplo em que o selected está no final:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form>
            <select required>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="vw">VW</option>
                <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
            </select>

            <button type = "submit">Enviar</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ou seja o selected está na última opção do select e funciona normalmente.

Se você quer que o selecione seja padrão e que ele seja enviado como valor é necessário que você defina desta forma:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form>
            <select required>
                <option value = "Selecione" selected>Selecione</option>
                <option value = "0,00">0, 00</option>
                <option value = "+0,25">+0, 25</option>
                <option value = "+0,50">+0, 50</option>
                <option value = "+0,75">+0, 75</option>
                <option value = "+1,00">+1, 00</option>
            </select>

            <button type = "submit">Enviar</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lembrando que a ordem não tem problema, apesar de ser interessante você colocar um valor padrão por início:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form>
            <select required>                
                <option value = "0,00">0, 00</option>
                <option value = "+0,25">+0, 25</option>
                <option value = "+0,50">+0, 50</option>
                <option value = "+0,75">+0, 75</option>
                <option value = "+1,00">+1, 00</option>
                <option value = "Selecione" selected>Selecione</option>
            </select>

            <button type = "submit">Enviar</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

se você criar um scrip simples de php para exibir os dados deste select assim que der um clique no botão submit, verá como ele assume o valor:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <form method="POST" action="dados.php">
            <select name="taxas" required>
                <option value = "Selecione" selected>Selecione</option>
                <option value = "0,00">0, 00</option>
                <option value = "+0,25">+0, 25</option>
                <option value = "+0,50">+0, 50</option>
                <option value = "+0,75">+0, 75</option>
                <option value = "+1,00">+1, 00</option>
            </select>

            <button type = "submit">Enviar</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

dados.php:

```
<?php

echo $taxa = $_POST['taxas'];
```